# Discord.js (v.14) Problem with Reaction Collector

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have in mind to create a little game on Discord, based on reaction collectors.
I would like my bot to randomly send messages with a reaction on it, and the users would react. Then, I set a collector that would collect how much time this user reacted in a day, and with an embed, the user could check how much time they reacted.
Currently, I encounter a few issues (and I also have some questions) regarding this.

First, when I react to the message for the first time, everything works well: the console.log indicates that I reacted. But when I try to do it a second time, the console.log indicates that I reacted 3 times, whereas I did it just once. Where does it come from?

Second, is there a way to do a kind of scoring system that would collect the amount of time an user reacted? (for example: in a day, I react to 10 different messages, is there a way to make a kind of inventory that would shown how many times I reacted?)

Here is the full code :

```
client.on("messageCreate", message =>{
    if(message.content === prefix + "m"){
      message.channel.send("Voici un oeuf de Pâques! Vite! Réagis avant qu'il ne disparaisse! :)")
    }
    client.on("messageCreate", message =>{
      if(message.content === "Voici un oeuf de Pâques! Vite! Réagis avant qu'il ne disparaisse! :)"){
          message.react('');
    

      const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id !== message.author.id;
      };

      const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 5000 });

      collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
      });

      collector.on('end', async collected => {
        console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
if(message.content === prefix + "c"){
  const infoEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor('Random')
    .setTitle(`Inventory`)
    .setDescription("Check how many Easter Eggs you collected!")
    .addFields(
      { name: 'Easter Eggs', value:`${collected.size}`})

      message.channel.send ({ embeds: [infoEmbed]})
    }
  })
})
      }
    })
  });
```

Thanks a lot for any help !

Comment: Why do you have so many event listeners? You shouldn't have more than one. Especially not inside the other ones' callbacks.

Comment: I edited my code and deleted the useless event listeners, and indeed it works better, 
I no longer have the problem about having 3 reactions that are logged. Thanks!